# mySQL return NO_DATA, but record exists

Tags: c++, mysql, libmysqlclient

Trying to run the following

```
std::wstring query1 = L"SELECT st.table_id FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLES st  WHERE st.name = ?;";
```

or

```
std::wstring query1 = L"SELECT st.table_id FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLES st  WHERE st.name = CONCAT(?, '/', ?);";
```

returns `SQL_NO_DATA`, but if the parameter is spelled out the record is returned.

Code is as follows:

```
auto res1 = mysql_stmt_init( m_db );
if( !res1 )
{
    std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
    errors.push_back( err );
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    if( mysql_stmt_prepare( res1, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query1.c_str() ).c_str(), query1.length() ) )
    {
        std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
        errors.push_back( err );
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        MYSQL_BIND params[2];
        unsigned long str_length1, str_length2;
        str_length1 = strlen( m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( schema.c_str() ) .c_str() ) * 2;
        str_length2 = strlen( m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( table.c_str() ).c_str() ) * 2;
        char *str_data1 = new char[str_length1], *str_data2 = new char[str_length2];
        memset( str_data1, '\0', str_length1 );
        memset( str_data2, '\0', str_length2 );
        memset( params, 0, sizeof( params ) );
        strncpy( str_data1, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( schema.c_str() ) .c_str(), str_length1 );
        strncpy( str_data2, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( table.c_str() ).c_str(), str_length2 );
        params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
        params[0].buffer = (char *) str_data1;
        params[0].buffer_length = strlen( str_data1 );
        params[0].is_null = 0;
        params[0].length = &str_length1;
        params[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
        params[1].buffer = (char *) str_data2;
        params[1].buffer_length = strlen( str_data2 );
        params[1].is_null = 0;
        params[1].length = &str_length2;
        if( mysql_stmt_bind_param( res1, params ) )
        {
            std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
            errors.push_back( err );
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            auto prepare_meta_result = mysql_stmt_result_metadata( res1 );
            if( !prepare_meta_result )
            {
                std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
                errors.push_back( err );
                result = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if( mysql_stmt_execute( res1 ) )
                {
                    std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
                    errors.push_back( err );
                    result = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    MYSQL_BIND results1[1];
                    bool is_null[1], error[1];
                    unsigned long length[1];
                    memset( results1, 0, sizeof( results1 ) );
                    results1[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
                    
                    results1[0].buffer = (char *) &tableId;
                    results1[0].is_null = &is_null[1];
                    results1[0].error = &error[1];
                    results1[0].length = &length[1];
                    
                    if( mysql_stmt_bind_result( res1, results1 ) )
                    {
                        std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
                        errors.push_back( err );
                        result = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while( true )
                        {
                            auto dataset = mysql_stmt_fetch( res1 );
                            if( dataset == 1 || dataset == MYSQL_NO_DATA )
                                break;
                            else
                                id = tableId;
                        }
                        mysql_free_result( prepare_meta_result );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if( mysql_stmt_close( res1 ) )
{
    std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
    errors.push_back( err );
    result = 1;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a very confusing mix of narrow vs wide characters here, and the fact that you're casting to `(char *)` raises huge red flags..  Why are `str_length1` and `str_length2` multiplied by 2?  Are they supposed to be Windows Unicode strings?  If so, then you cannot use `strncpy` to copy them.

Comment: @TimRoberts, thats should be cross-platform. The query is written in wstring because the schema and the table are passed as `wstring`and so it will be easier to convert .

Comment: As I'm using `mySQL C API` I have to convert back and force.

Comment: OK, but if `m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes()` is returning an 8-bit string, as the code implies, then you absolutely do not want the `* 2` you have on both of those statements.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I changed it to `= 2` to account for '\0', but still got the `NO_DATA`.

Comment: Did you mean `+2`?  And you should remove most of the `(char *)` casts.  If that results in an error, then you need to fix the error.  Casts hide many legitimate errors.

Comment: @TimRoberts, ok, I got rid of all castings and still get `NO_DATA`. Any other idea? Let me know if you want me to update the code..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a lifetime issue.  Consider the following code:

```
{
    if( mysql_stmt_prepare( res1, m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query1.c_str() ).c_str(), query1.length() ) )
    {
```

You take your `wstring query1` (and WHY is it a wstring if you need it to be a std::string???), and pass it to `m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes`.  I assume that function does the Unicode-to-ANSI translation and returns a `std::string`.  You then call `c_str()` on that to get a buffer, and pass that to `mysql_stmt_prepare`.

HOWEVER, what `to_bytes` returns is a temporary.  As soon as the `if` statement exits, that string goes out of scope and will be destroyed, leaving the statement holding a pointer into nothing.  I suggest you try:

```
    std::string query1s = m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( query1.c_str() );
    if( mysql_stmt_prepare( res1, query1s.c_str(), query1s.length() ) )
    {
```

This has the additional benefit of letting you print the value of `query1s` to make sure it matches your expectation.

Now, IF `mysql_stmt_prepare` actually copies the input string, instead of just grabbing a pointer, then this won't fix anything.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html, the cast to the result column should be there.

Comment: Only if the data is not already a string.  You have to look at what the code is doing, and not just copy it blindly.